# Increase Value with useState using ReactJS Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new developer at ReactJs world. I have a question. I have value variable with initial value as 1. But I have a problem while increasing it. In JavaScript I can incarease an any value one by one  but I did not make same thing using Hooks. The thing which I want to do is changing background image with time. Could you help me at this issue? How can I change my background image with time ?

my example tsx.part:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const LeftPart = (props: any) => {

     let imgNumber : number = 1;

     const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

     useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            imgNumber = imgNumber + 1;
            setValue(value+1);

            console.log(imgNumber)
            console.log(value)
        }, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);

    return (

        <div className="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm col-12">
            <img id="image" src={"../../../assets/images/bg"+{value}+".jpg"} style={{ width: "100%", height: "99vh" }} alt="Login Images"></img>
        </div >
    )
}

export default LeftPart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `useEffect` block dependency list (that empty array). When you explicitly set no dependencies, React will call the callback on first render and never again. If you want it to continuously change, just remove that second parameter entirely. If you implicitly leave no `useEffect` dependencies, it is called on every render.

Fixed:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        imgNumber = imgNumber + 1;
        setValue(value+1);
        console.log(imgNumber)
        console.log(value)
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: i did it but ı am facing a loop. It is rendering so much. Why ? Do you know it ?

Comment: With this code it should render once every three seconds, no more. If it's rerendering faster than that there's some other reason (maybe its parents are rerendering or its props are changing?) In any case, create a new question if you have a new issue.